# MethodNotAllowedHttpException at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))

Tags: laravel, post, laravel-5

I'm trying to use POST to let user log in with correct email/password. I keep getting this error

MethodNotAllowedHttpException at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::post("/login",[UserController::class,'login']);
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    function login(request $req)
    {
        return $req->input();
    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="container custom-login">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <form action="/login" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                @csrf
                <labe for="exampleInputEmail">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <labe for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

I tried opening the login page but POST is having issues. I expected the login page to use POST to check credentials in my database.

Comment: laravel version is 5.4.36

Comment: I figured it out in web.php at ``` Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
}); ```   needed to be changed to ``` Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
}); ```           but then i had a different error and  innovin's recomendation fixed it! I changed the login route name like he said and boom fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Your routes might be cached. First clear your routes cache via terminal: `php artisan route:clear`

Afterwards, run `php artisan route:list` and verify that your routes are correct.

If that does not make the form work, then proceed further:

Give your login route a name as such:

```
Route::post("login",[UserController::class,'login'])->name('user.login');
```

Then pass it to your form action using the `route()` helper function like this:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="container custom-login">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <form action="{{ route('user.login') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                @csrf
                <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Tried both suggestions with no luck. heres what the route:list returned

Comment: | Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |

|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | login    |      | Closure | web          |